# UIButton in non-visible area of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview

How can I get a button tap for a button which is located in a UIScrollView, but in its initially non-visible area?

**Solved**
Problem was that the content was visible within a non-clipped view - therefore not getting touches.

Comment: The button inside the scrollview is an UIButton?

Comment: if the button is not visible, where do you want the user to tap?

Comment: @Matteo: Yes, a UIButton

Comment: @Guy: when it scrolls into view...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add an action (yourAction in the code below) to the UIButton.

programmatically:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)yourAction:(id)sender{
    // your code
}
```

With the gui builder you should connect your UIButton to an action defined as IBAction in your .h controller file:

```
-(IBAction)yourAction:(id)sender;
```