# UITapGestureRecognizer only triggered for starting area of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have several sub views added to a UIScrollView in the main view controller. Each sub view's view controller has its  own tap recognizer. The problem is, only tapping in the starting area on the screen is recognised. After scrolling the view and tapping beyond the starting area, the tapping handler will no longer be called.

This SO post [UIButton in non-visible area of UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011073/uibutton-in-non-visible-area-of-uiscrollview) seems to be relevant but its solution description wasn't really clear to me...

A simple report project could be found at: [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qk892k7hbil2ub/Detecting%20Tap%20Gestures.zip?dl=0)

Thanks.

Comment: what is issue , you have added tap gesture for both part ?

Comment: The scroll view's content size is 2000*800, which is larger than the screen size. When the app is initially launched and user tapes, the tap handler is recognised. If you scroll the screen to the right and tap on the right-most area, the tap handler will no longer be triggered.

Comment: @MikeAlter by both part do you mean the visible and invisible parts of the scroll view? If so, how do I add tap gesture for the part beyond the visible area initially?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `contentview` size or `setbackground color` for `scrollview` and `contentview`. `Contenview` size is not increasing i think.

Comment: Sorry if I missed something obvious. How do I check contentview. I'm not using it anywhere. BTW, I checked scrollview's size and it is for sure set to be large enough. I have setbackground color as well in the simple repro. Thanks.

Comment: Still you are facing issue?

Comment: @jackX. what was the solution?

Comment: @AviTsadok Check your contentview's height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded your project and  see that   the

```
SSubViewController *pvc = [SSubViewController controllerWithSubViewID:0];
```

`pvc` frame is out of bound

```
SSubViewController *pvc = [SSubViewController controllerWithSubViewID:0];
[self.scrollView addSubview:pvc.view];
[self addChildViewController:pvc];
[pvc.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[pvc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 200)];

[pvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

SSubViewController *pvc1 = [SSubViewController controllerWithSubViewID:1];
[self.scrollView addSubview:pvc1.view];
[pvc1.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[self addChildViewController:pvc1];
[pvc1 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[pvc1.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 400, 200)];
```

Now see the Colours

[image]

As you can see Gray color, and Yellow color  frame

Comment: Got it. And that works. Thanks for the detailed explanation Mike!